# Attribute is missing the namespace prefix

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top">
    <TextViewandroid:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="OK" />
<Button
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ok"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_below="@+id/entry"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've just started to learn Android apk programming and I have encountered this problem: "Attribute is missing the namespace prefix". 
How can I fix this? Please reply.. any reply would be wonderful thanks

Comment: make one space before `android:id` at `<TextViewandroid:id="@+id/label"`

Comment: ahh yeah its my bad I didn't see that.. hehe
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the spacing . try this ..

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top">
   <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:"/>
   <EditText
     android:id="@+id/entry"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/label"/>
   <Button
     android:id="@+id/ok"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/entry"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
     android:text="OK" />
   <Button
     android:layout_alignTop="@id/ok"
     android:text="Cancel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_below="@+id/entry"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ohh yeah thank you so much that's really help.. :D
I still have a lot to learn.. and there is still more question to come haha .. hope you can give an reply again.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
TextViewandroid:id="@+id/label"
```

to:

```
TextView android:id="@+id/label"
```

Answer (score 0):

u shud give some space after the widget name. replace below code it will work.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:"/>
```